# Chrome instances move to same virtual desktop after sleep or hibernate in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, virtual-desktop

I use Google Chrome on Windows 10, and I like to keep one window with a set of tabs in one virtual desktop and another Chrome window in a different desktop

Frequently after sleeping or hibernating my computer for a while, I find that all my Chrome windows have conglomerated in one desktop. Just now it happened the moment I clicked on my first Chrome window after resuming the computer. However, I can't figure out the precise steps to make this problem happen, so I'm not sure what causes it.

Is this likely to be a bug in Chrome? Or something that I fix somehow?

Comment: I suspect the problem is that your monitor isn't 'ready' when chrome is coming back up, so it all gets pushed back onto one desktop. I only think this as I *don't* have the same issue.

Comment: Same problem, all ~20 windows move to a single virtual desktop after resuming from hibernation. This began happening within the last month or two, so possibly caused by the Anniversary update, but Chrome has had some big updates recently as well.

Comment: Anyone found a solution to this? It's pretty irritating, since the only way to separate "workspaces" in Chrome is via multiple windows.

Comment: I have not noticed this problem in recent months--or at least not as much, so it's possible that it was improved in a Windows or Chrome update. But no definitive solution.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same issue for sooo long. And now I'm facing the problem cause it's enough, I can't with it.

Can't find nothing searching on the web. But I think I know when it happens.

Apparently it only happens when hibernate with a second monitor plugged.

So my workaround will be to first unplug the second monitor and then to hibernate. I know it will move all of my opened windows to my laptop. But IMHO it's better than moving everything without any order across my virtual desktops.

I hope this helps and please tell me if there is a better solution

Comment: I agree this seems like the best workaround. Haven't tried it yet (no time), but I believe it'll work. Just have to remember to first unplug external monitor before going to hibernate...

Answer (score 1):

Not the solution you are looking for but they way I make it work is to use Firefox on one desktop and Chrome on the other.

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution but a workaround: hit CTRL-WINDOWS-RIGHT ARROW, then immediately CTRL-WINDOWS-LEFT ARROW (or UP/DOWN if you have your virtual windows above and below). This will quickly move you to another virtual desktop and back. This "reminds" Chrome about the orientation and gets you quickly back to your original configuration.

It's worth noting that this also triggers when you have your desktop set to automatically switch your desktop images in the Personalization Settings. Really annoying when you have it set to every 30 minutes, as I did!